# Does Dr. Sinclair's Epigenome Resetting in ICE Mice Also Repair Telomere Length?"

Tags: senescence

Dr. Sinclair's team at Harvard University has published a paper this year on rejuvenating ICE mice by reprogramming cells to reset the epigenome. Does this cellular reprogramming also repair the length of telomeres?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please finish reading the [Tour] and the Help on asking questions. Regardless of who was the captain of the team and where they play, without a link to the paper, most list members will ignore your question. You can't expect us to go searching for it. The second point is whether you are asking if the information is in the paper, in which case you should point out where this isn't clear, or whether you really expect someone on this list to know about the group's unpublished work.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very informative. I will take measures from now on.